# Instantiate a hive object from json while preserving the key

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, mixins, flutter-hive

When my class is extending `HiveObject` I have access to `key` using the getter defined in `HiveObjectMixin` but after sending the class instance through the network as JSON I need to convert it back to a model using `Model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)` but I can't set the key since it is private and the HiveObjectMixin is not defining a setter

```dart
class User extends HiveObject {
  final String name;

  User({required this.name});

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      name: map['name'], // <<here I need to set key as well but I can't
    );
  }
}
```

How can I define a fromMap factory that returns a model with the sam key in the map/json ?